# How do I use fscanf to capture space?

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to C programming, and I am learning to use fscanf function (or the scanf family functions.). I am having some trouble understanding how to use fscanf function to capture the whitespace.

Suppose I have the following scenario, I have opened a file, and file only contains one line of character, and the layout of the only line in this file is:

A_C

A is a sequence of characters, which is a string.

_ is a white space, I use _ to show it more clearly.

C is a sequence of characters, which is a string.

In this scenario, _ will always stays as a white space. A or C might be a single white space as wll.

My question is, how do I use fscanf function to capture both A and C? Regardless of whether they are whitespace or the actual sequence of characters? That being said, if A is a sequence of characters, then I capture this sequence of characters, if A is a whitespace, I capture this whitespace? (Same idea applies to C).

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand you statement. In this example: `"a b c d e"` what are `A` and `C` and why?

Comment: You can't use `fscanf` and you don't use it. Just use `getchar()` and similar, and write your own parser, for you own specific needs.

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't state it clearly.

Assume the following is my file:

0x123456 0x67891.

I only have this line in my file, I want to capture both hex numbers respectively, yes I understand that we can just use %lx %lx to capture this two numbers, but the problem is, these two numbers might be just white space, like
_ _ 0x67891, I have to figure out a way using only fscanf to determine if the first hex number is whitespace or the second hex number is white space.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Show what you have tried yourself. Help community to help you

Comment: Like Kamil Cuk mentioned, you should process it char-by-char. Another option is to use `fgets` and work with the entire string in memory (it may be simpler).

Comment: It seems like you just have to check the first character of the input. If the first character is space, then `A` is a space and `B` is everything after the next space. If the first character is not a space, `A` is the first string and `B` is everything after the first space.

Comment: But will fgets skip the leadning whitespaces?

Comment: @Metaozis No, `fgets()` reads a whole line, it doesn't skip anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char str[BUFF_SIZE];

fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp);

if (the first char is a space) {
    Means A == " ";
}

if (the last char is a space) {
    Means B == " ";
}

if (both are spaces) {
    done;
} else if (only one is space) {
    sscanf(scan for one string, which will be the one that wasn't a space);
} else {
    sscanf(scan for two strings, separated by a space);
}
```

It could be doable in a single line, fscanf is very powerful, but I have never tried things that complicate too much, and someone else may explain that better.  However, this should work.

Comment: This should use `sscanf()` rather than `fscanf()`, because you need to read the whole line first to tell if first or last char is space.